# React router protected routes redirecting on page reload

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following App component with a react-router setup. The `/orders` URL is to be protected using the RouteGuard.js component, which redirects you to `/login` if you are not logged in and try to access `/orders`. Now, this setup works wonderfully as I am unable to access `/orders` unless I sign in or the app loads the logged previously logged-in user through cookies.

However, the setup fails **when I am already logged in and go to `/orders`, and from there reload (F5)**. What happens when I press F5 while inside /orders, I get redirected to `/login` even though my cookie still exists and I am still logged in.

Somehow the RouteGuard component gets fired first before the `useEffect` hook from the App component, as evidenced by my console logging.

**Console.log output:**

> App.js User Authenticated? false

> isAuthenticated from RouteGuard.js false

> USER AUTHENTICATED SET TO TRUE

> App.js User Authenticated? true

**App.js**

```js
const App = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // CHECK IF THERE IS A LOGGED IN USER FROM PREVIOUS SESSIONS
    const loggedUserJSON = Cookies.get("loggedInUser");
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      let parsedUser = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON);
      setUser(parsedUser);
      UserService.setAuthenticated(true);
      console.log("USER AUTHENTICATED SET TO TRUE");
    }
  }, []);
  console.log("App.js User Authenticated?", UserService.isAuthenticated());

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <RouteGuard
            auth={UserService.isAuthenticated()}
            path="/orders"
            component={Orders}
          />
```

**RouteGuard.js**

```js
const RouteGuard = ({ auth, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  console.log(
    "isAuthenticated from RouteGuard.js",
    UserService.isAuthenticated()
  );

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      // if auth is true, then render the passed component, else redirect to /login
      render={(props) =>
        auth ? (
          <Component />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: {
                error: "You must login to continue.",
                from: props.location,
                redirected: true,
              },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

**Also the UserService file, if it would be of any help**

```js
let authenticated = false;

const setAuthenticated = (bool) => {
  // TRUE OR FALSE
  authenticated = bool;
};

const isAuthenticated = () => authenticated;
```

Comment: could you try keeping a console.log outside useeffect in the app component, and show the output

Comment: The behaviour is expected. When you refresh the page inside /orders.. RouteGuard component is mounted first and then the parent component is mounted.

Comment: @adhinarayan I have added a console.log outside the useEffect hook.
Check out the post, I have edited the response now.  Is there a way to make the useEffect from App fire first before the RouteGuard component?

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` wil only execute after render, as it will only execute on `componentDidMount`, so what you're seeing is expected.

I'd suggest reworking your code to either remove the ```` useEffect```, I'm not sure why you've used it at all (unless you're perhaps rendering that server side).  Alternatively use a state update so that you can trigger another rerender when ```` useEffect```` completes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot make useEffect fire before the child component gets mounted.  One solution would be to rerender the parent component using some state. I have done the same below

```
const App = (props) => {
  let [loggedIn, setLoggenIn] = useState(UserService.isAuthenticated())
  useEffect(() => {
    // CHECK IF THERE IS A LOGGED IN USER FROM PREVIOUS SESSIONS
    const loggedUserJSON = Cookies.get("loggedInUser");
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      let parsedUser = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON);
      setUser(parsedUser);
      UserService.setAuthenticated(true);
      setLoggenIn(true)
      console.log("USER AUTHENTICATED SET TO TRUE");
    }
  }, []);
  console.log("App.js User Authenticated?", UserService.isAuthenticated());

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <RouteGuard
            auth={UserService.isAuthenticated()}
            path="/orders"
            component={Orders}
          />
```